# Android: Views in TableLayout added programatically not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm creating an app and I need to have dynamic tables inside it so I tried to do so and for the most part, it works. But I have these dividers between my rows and columns, I used Views to do so and they come out like this:

EDIT: I Think the views are just not being shown and my first column is where the left border should be, don't know what is doing this though.

[image: Dividers appear in the title row]

This is the code I use to generate the rows:

```
private void generateMaterialRows(){
        TableLayout tableMaterials = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.info_table_materials);
            //create counter for index in table
            int c = 3;
        for(Material m: materials){


            //makes Rows
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow tDivider = new TableRow(this);

            //Makes 5 bottomBorders and puts them in an Array
            View[] bottomBorders = new View[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                View bottomBorder = new View(this);
                bottomBorder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorDarkGray);
                int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 3, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); //converts dp to px
                bottomBorder.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));
                bottomBorder.setLayoutParams(bottomBorder.getLayoutParams());

                bottomBorders[i] = bottomBorder;
            }

            //makes 3 sideBorders and puts them in an Array
            View[] sideBorders = new View[3];

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                View sideBorder = new View(this);
                sideBorder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorDarkGray);
                int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 3, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); //converts dp to px
                sideBorder.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                sideBorder.setLayoutParams(sideBorder.getLayoutParams());

                sideBorders[i] = sideBorder;
            }

            //makes columnAmount
            TextView txtAmount = new TextView(this);
            txtAmount.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorBlueLight);
            txtAmount.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
            txtAmount.setText(String.valueOf(m.getAmount()));

            //makes columnName
            TextView txtName = new TextView(this);
            txtName.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorBlueLight);
            txtName.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            txtName.setText(String.valueOf(m.getName()));

            //puts content in TableRow
            tRow.addView(sideBorders[0]);
            tRow.addView(txtAmount);
            tRow.addView(sideBorders[1]);
            tRow.addView(txtName);
            tRow.addView(sideBorders[2]);

            //makes divider
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                tDivider.addView(bottomBorders[i]);
            }

            tableMaterials.addView(tRow, c);
            tableMaterials.addView(tDivider, c+1);

            c++;
        }
    }
```

This is the TableLayout in the XML:

```
                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/info_table_materials"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
                    <!-- Divider Above Title Row -->
                    <TableRow>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                    </TableRow>

                    <!-- Title Row -->
                    <TableRow>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_width="3px"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/info_amount"
                            android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_width="3px"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/info_materials"
                            android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_width="3px"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                    </TableRow>

                    <!-- Divider Between Title and Content Rows -->
                    <TableRow>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                        <View
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:layout_height="3px"/>
                    </TableRow>

                </TableLayout>
```

I'm still fairly new at android so I'm still learning but this one got me real confused and I can't seem to find what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I had no clue how to use the `LayoutParams` so I used `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` but since they are in a `TableRow` I should have used `TableRow.LayoutParams`